# como trabalhar com PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, partial, partialview

Eu tenho o Cadastro de Pessoas, e tenho o Cadastro de Endereços, que estão em duas classes separadas, pois o objetivo é que o usuário possa ter 2 ou mais endereços, como o de entrega, e o de cobrança. Então queria saber como faço para utilizar a PartialView. no caso eu Gerei 2 scaffold, sendo 1 do cadastro de Pessoas, e outro do endereço.

Queria saber como montar em uma única tela o cadastro de pessoa + o endereço, pelas pesquisas que eu vi é utilizando o PartialView, porém não consegui desenvolver nada.

Segue os componentes:

Classes:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome")]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 2 e no máximo 150 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Celular")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("WhatsApp")]
    public string Whatsapp { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O E-mail deve ter no máximo 150 caracteres.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CPF")]
    [DisplayName("CPF")]
    [StringLength(14, MinimumLength = 14, ErrorMessage = "O CPF deve 14 caracteres.")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("CNPJ")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    public int Tipo { get; set; }


    //relacionamentos
    public virtual ICollection<PessoaEndereco> PessoasEnderecos { get; set; }
}


public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o endereço")]
    [DisplayName("Endereço")]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "O endereço deve ter no mínimo 2 e no máximo 150 caracteres.")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o numero")]
    [DisplayName("Numero")]
    //[StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "O numero da residência deve ter no mínimo 1 e no máximo 5 caracteres.")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o bairro")]
    [DisplayName("Bairro")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O bairro deve ter no mínimo 3 e no máximo 100 caracteres.")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CEP")]
    [DisplayName("CEP")]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "O CEP possui 9 caracteres.")]
    public string CEP { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Comlemento")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    //Relacionamentos
    public int LogradouroID { get; set; }
    public virtual Logradouro Logradouro { get; set; }

    public int CidadeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PessoaEndereco> PessoasEnderecos { get; set; }

}
```

O Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PessoaID,Nome,Telefone,Celular,Whatsapp,Email,CPF,Tipo,RG,Senha")] Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        pessoa.Tipo = 1;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(pessoa);
    }
```

então criei esta PartialView e gerei o scaffold dela do tipo empty:

```
    public PartialViewResult CadastroUsuarioEndereco()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Na partial coloquei iniciando da linha 1:

```
@{
Html.RenderPartial("Create");
}
```

e na quarta linha fiz o mesmo, porém como é de outro controller, onde passo o endereço coloquei `("NomedaView","Controller")`, mas dai ele deu erro em um monte de coisa, que não da erro se rodar cada tela individualmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que criar um arquivo (`.cshtml`) separado para ser sua PartialView e nele colocar os dados que deseja cadastrar. Por exemplo, para criar a partial `_CadastrarEndereco.cshtml`:

```
@model iClips.Models.Objetos.Pessoa

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor("Numero")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Numero)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor("Bairro")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Bairro)
</div>
```

No seu controller, você coloca o nome da partial:

```
public PartialViewResult CadastroUsuarioEndereco()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Cadastro/_CadastrarEndereco");
}
```

Para renderizar a partial você coloca na view onde a partial vai ser renderizada, não na partial em questão

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Controller/_CadastrarEndereco.cshtml")
```

Obs.: Você disse na pergunta "então criei esta PartialView.." e colocou o código do controller, uma PartialView é uma parte da view, ou seja, é HTML. Essa parte do seu controller chama a partial.

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Controller/View.cshtml");
}
```

Substituindo **Controller** pelo nome da pasta onde foi gerado sua partial view e **View.cshtml** pelo nome da sua partial view.