# Criar Partial para Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu gostaria de criar uma partial (pra ser chamada como @Html.Partial) recebendo o id da tabela e uma coleção da dados. Porém, teria que ser totalmente independente.
A parte do C#, com reflection, eu consigo fazer numa boa, mas não sei como criar isso no MVC.

Como eu posso criar uma extensão pro Html do MVC e chamar uma função Table, recebendo esses parâmetros? E como chamar, internamente, uma view e um controller pré-definidos?

Comment: Tu está tentando passar dois parâmetros para a partial (um id e uma coleção)?

Comment: User, sua pergunta é muito genérica, fica difícil te ajudar. posta o código que voce está fazendo que fica mais fácil.

Comment: Talvez te ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166077/51124